# Multiple Inner Joins with Polymorphic Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following polymorphic association...

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities, as: :owner
end

class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities, as: :owner
end
```

I am trying to make a query whereby it only pulls out the activities where the owner (user or manager) has `visible` set to `true`.

I have figured out that if I want to do this for one of the owners, I can do this as follows...

```
Activity.joins("INNER JOIN users ON activities.owner_id = users.id").where(:activities => {:owner_type => 'User'}).where(:users => {:visible => true})
```

But I cannot figure out how to do it for both. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
Activity.
  joins("LEFT JOIN users ON activities.owner_type = 'User' AND
                            activities.owner_id = users.id").
  joins("LEFT JOIN managers ON activities.owner_type = 'Manager' AND
                               activities.owner_id = managers.id").
  where("users.visible = ? OR managers.visible = ?", true, true)
```

Comment: Awesome! I just ran it and it works, and on postgres too. Thanks a lot. This had me scratching my head for a while :)

Comment: Glad to help! I'm a but rusty on SQL, but after some tries, I finally managed to do it :)